# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el último día de cada mes?

Tags: java

Actualmente tengo un sistema que me genera los meses que voy a necesitar de acuerdo a la cantidad de meses que necesito generar por medio de un `jSpinner`, es decir si le dejo el valor de `4` me genera a partir de la fecha actual 4 meses.

Por ejemplo, estamos en marzo entonces genera:

1. Marzo
2. Abril
3. Mayo
4. Junio

Hasta ahí todo está bien, el detalle está cuando necesito que me genere pero de esos meses el último día de cada mes, encontré aquí en SO Es unas funciones para lograrlo, el problema es que me devuelve solo los días y no la fecha completa en formato `día/mes/año` por decir, si estamos en febrero me devuelve: 28 y si es marzo me devuelve 31 y lo que necesito es que me arroje `31/01/2022` , `28/02/2022` consecutivamente.

Éste es el código que empleo:

```
private void prueba(){
    try {            
        //SE OBTIENE LA FECHA:
        
        int año= calendarioFechaHOY.getDate().getYear()+1900;
        int mes0= calendarioFechaHOY.getDate().getMonth()+1;
        int dias= calendarioFechaHOY.getDate().getDate();
                
        String f0=( String.valueOf(dias"/"+(mes0-1)+"/"+año));
        String fecha1 = f0;            
        SimpleDateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        int mes = Integer.parseInt(jSpinner1.getValue().toString());
        String dateInicio = fecha1;

        Date fecha = dFormat.parse(dateInicio);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(fecha);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < mes; i++){
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            dateInicio = dFormat.format(cal.getTime()); 
            System.out.println(dateInicio);
            fechasRecibo.add(dFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
            fechasLimite.add(String.valueOf(cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
        }            
        fechasLimite.forEach(c -> {
            System.out.println("Fecha: " + c);
            }});            
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
        }  
        contadorTablaGrupos();
        //final ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(principalForm.class.getResource("/iconos/prestamoOK64.png"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html><b><H1 align=\"center\">RECIBOS GENERADOS:</font></H1></b>"
                + "</html>","RECIBOS GENERADOS CORRECTAMENTE",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas esto te puede servir:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println("1-Último día del " + calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta aunque ya lo resolví, ya había visto ese código pero solo te devuelve el día por ejemplo en este mes de abril solo te devuelve 30 y yo necesitaba con formato día, mes y año es decir 30/04/2022 pero ya un gran amigo me ayudo realizando las operaciones entre los días para obtener el ultimo, de todas formas muchas gracias!